# Create temporary file in Python that will be deleted automatically after sometime

Tags: python, temporary-files

Is it possible to create temporary files in python that will be deleted after some time? I checked [tempfile](https://docs.python.org/2/library/tempfile.html) library which generates temporary files and directories.

> [tempfile.TemporaryFile](https://docs.python.org/2/library/tempfile.html#tempfile.TemporaryFile) : This function creates tempfile which will be destroyed as soon as closed.
>
> [tempfile.NamedTemporaryFile](https://docs.python.org/2/library/tempfile.html#tempfile.NamedTemporaryFile): This function accepts a parameter *delete*. If delete is given the value *false* while calling the function the file will not be deleted on close.

What I need is a temp file which I should be able to read with its name for some time even after I close it. However, It should be deleted automatically after some time.

What is the easiest way to do this in Python 2.7?

Comment: Do you plan to read it within the same script?

Comment: No, I will have the file name and need to read it later using that name.

Answer (score 3):

If you only need to run the file at intervals *within* your Python program, you can use it as a context manager:

```
def main(file_object):
    # Can read and write to file_object at any time within this function

if __name__ == '__main__':
    with tempfile.NamedTemporaryFile() as file_object:
        main(file_object)
        # Can still use file_object
    # file_object is referencing a closed and deleted file here
```

If you need to be able to open it outside of the Python program, say after `main` is over, like in a process that runs asyncronously, you should probably look for a more permenant solution (e.g. allowing the user to specify the file name.)

If you really needed to have a temporary auto-deleting file, you can start a `threading.Timer` to delete it after some time, but make sure that your program deletes it even if it is stopped before the timer ends.